# Splitting an expression containing strings of different lengths followed by numbers in R

Tags: r, string, split

I have a list of compounds like the following:

[image]

I need to split and place an underscore in between element names. Now the element names can be single Capital letter, or 1 Capital letter followed by a small letter. I have achieved so far placing a '_' in between strings containing 2 letters. However whenever a Single letter element is concerned it is giving the following:

"Element V1.0 in compound Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.0_5_Nb_0.5_6_Ni_1.0 entered does not exist!". (Error message generated by the code) However I want it to be the following:

"V_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.05_Nb_0.56_Ni_1.0"

So it is not only grouping single letters with numbers, it is also failing to identify all numbers grouped together. Can anyone please help? I used the following code to achieve this:

```
elem = gsub("(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[0-9A-Z])", "_", elem, perl = TRUE)
```

where elem is my list of compounds.

The numbers are basically element fractions, So the error message should read like:

Error: Element 'Cz' (or 'Z' a single letter element which does not exist in the periodic table), " in compound xyz entered does not exist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may remove the substring that doesn't match and then do the insertion of `_`

```
gsub("([A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9])", "\\1_\\2", 
   gsub("([A-Za-z]+)_?([0-9._]+)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.", "", elem, perl = TRUE))
```

-output

```
[1] "V_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.0_5_Nb_0.5_6_Ni_1.0"
```

---

Based on the comments, we may add a new `gsub` on top of the above to remove the `_` between the digits

```
gsub("([0-9])_([0-9])", "\\1\\2", gsub("([A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9])", "\\1_\\2", 
   gsub("([A-Za-z]+)_?([0-9._]+)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.", "", elem, perl = TRUE)))
[1] "V_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.05_Nb_0.56_Ni_1.0"
```

---

Based on new pattern

```
gsub("([0-9])_([0-9])", "\\1\\2", gsub("([A-Za-z0-9])([A-Z0-9])", "\\1_\\2", 
   gsub("([A-Za-z]+)_?([0-9._]+)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.", "", elem2, perl = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
[1] "V_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.05_Nb_0.56_Ni_1.0"  
[2] "Cr_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.05_Nb_0.56_Ni_1.0"
```

---

Or do an extraction with `str_extract` and then do the replacement and `paste`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
map_chr(str_extract_all(elem2, "[A-Za-z]+_?[0-9._]+"),
 ~ str_c(str_replace(str_remove_all(trimws(.x, whitespace = "_"), 
    "(?<=[0-9])_(?=[0-9])"), "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])", "_"), 
      collapse = "_"))
[1] "V_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.05_Nb_0.56_Ni_1.0"  
[2] "Cr_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.05_Nb_0.56_Ni_1.0"
```

#### data

```
elem <- "Element V1.0 in compound Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.0_5_Nb_0.5_6_Ni_1.0 entered does not exist!"
elem2 <- c("Element V1.0 in compound Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.0_5_Nb_0.5_6_Ni_1.0 entered does not exist!", 
"Element Cr1.0 in compound Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.0_5_Nb_0.5_6_Ni_1.0 entered does not exist!"
)
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks a lot. But I may have mentioned one thing wrong. It still does not group all the numbers together. I want it as "V_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.05_Nb_0.56_Ni_1.0" instead of "V_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.0_5_Nb_0.5_6_Ni_1.0". Can you help? I am still new to regex, hence having a bit of difficulty in understanding.

Comment: @user16754004 sorry i was looking at your expected `"V_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.0_5_Nb_0.5_6_Ni_1.0"` in the post

Comment: Understood. Its my bad I put it wrong in the first place.

Comment: Any help/idea is appreciated.

Comment: Great! Thanks a ton and much appreciated.

Comment: The solution is working for compounds with Single element at the start. However for compounds like 'Co0.62Cr0.62Cu0.62Fe0.62Ni0.62' with 2 letters at the start its not working.

Comment: @user16754004 can you check the update.  I am not sure what all other patterns you have in the original data

Comment: Can I send you an email with just a table with a single column containing the patterns/compounds? Its a bit difficult for me to navigate through this list as I have very little knowledge about R.

Comment: @user16754004 I would say to post as a new question that includes all the patterns and the expected output so that others will also see the question and contribute to solutions if they have.  When you post with a single pattern and output, and when we use regex, it is only based on that pattern

Comment: Ok then, updating this post. This is my very first post here, and I know little of this too.

Comment: @user16754004 please post as a new question as I already spent a lot of time on this post thinking that your pattern is based on the one posted

Comment: @user16754004 can you try with `map_chr(str_extract_all(elem, "[A-Za-z]+_?[0-9._]+"), ~ str_c(str_replace(str_remove_all(trimws(.x, whitespace = "_"), "(?<=[0-9])_(?=[0-9])"), "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])", "_"), collapse = "_"))`

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your previous message. I have posed it as a new qs.